# How can I translate Webrequest method in HttpClient

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I have this code for recovering Http code and description, but Visual Studio says that `WebRequest` is obsolete and that I have to use `HttpClient`. I'm not familiar with `HttpClient` can you help me?

```
IConfigurationRoot config;

myRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp($"{config["BASE_URL"]}{link}");
myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();
Check_load($"{config["BASE_URL"]}{link}");

var code = ((int)myResponse.StatusCode);  
var desc = myResponse.StatusDescription;
```

Comment: I would suggest you look at this MSDN https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0

Comment: What did you try so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: BTW the `StatusDescription` is accessible here as [`ReasonPhrase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.reasonphrase?view=net-6.0#system-net-http-httpresponsemessage-reasonphrase) as a part of the `HttpResponseMessage`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
var statusCode = response.StatusCode;
var content = response.Content;
if(statusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK && statusCode != HttpStatusCode.Created){
   //return something, error, description
}
```

**Update**
From comment `@Charlieface` pointed out where I haven't declared `HttpClient` as static field.
 To avoid creating instances of `HttpClient` every time it is called, the complete workground as below.

```
public class HttpHelper{
   private static HttpClent client = new HttpClient();

   public static async Task<string> GetAsync(string url)
   {
      var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
      var statusCode = response.StatusCode;
      var content = response.Content;
      if(statusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK && statusCode != HttpStatusCode.Created)
      {
         //return something, error, description
         //return $"error with status code: {statusCode}";
      }
      else
      {
         //return "success";
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Missing `using` blocks

Comment: @Charlieface as for me I never use HttpClient but RestSharp instead. 
ref to some article [YOU'RE USING HTTPCLIENT WRONG](https://www.westerndevs.com/Deployment/httpclientwrong/) as there are other articles talking about it too.

Comment: I'm aware of that article, which advises to *cache* `HttpClient` in a static field (which does not require `using`), not create it in a local and dump it (if you do this then you need `using`). And `response` requires disposing regardless, which was actually what I was talking about.

Comment: @Charlieface my fault haven't set HttpClient as static, but still not prefer the `using` block.
I will update my answer as you mentioned, thank you.

Comment: According to question I do not need to do with `content` what only need is to describe the `statusCode`  reading content is another thing.

Comment: As I said, `response` needs a using anyway, as does `content`. It makes no difference if you "do anything" with it, if you create it you must dispose it

Answer (score 0):

The use of HttpClient is very simple. See the code below

```
        try
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var res = await client.GetAsync(url);
                var response = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(response);
                // use the new data retreived...
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            responseMessage = new BadRequestObjectResult("error retreiving data");
        }
```

This suppose your data are sent in JSON format

Comment: Please do not suggest [wrong usage of HttpClient](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

Comment: @PeterCsala When used in high-load environments, it can cause deadlocks because it may encounter thread-safe problems in some cases. In dot net core, we have IHttpClientFactory, and I think using the factory pattern is much better.

Comment: In case of .NET Core the `HttpClientFactory` reuses the `HttpMessageHandler`s not the `HttpClient`s. So, there you can dispose the `HttpClient`s because they are created with `disposeHandler` = `false`.